# Hangfire fetching database every 15 second

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, hangfire

I use Recurring Job to call my function Test() with Cron.Daily() .
I does not need to fetch database every 15 second , my function executed every day only once .

how to stop hangfire to fetch database every 15 second ? or update interval.

this is configuration I am using it.

```
services.AddHangfire(config =>
config.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
.UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
.UseDefaultTypeSerializer()
.UseSqlServerStorage(configuration.GetConnectionString(“BackOffice”))
);
var sqlStorage = new SqlServerStorage(configuration.GetConnectionString(“BackOffice”));
JobStorage.Current = sqlStorage;

services.AddHangfireServer(sqlStorage);
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(configuration.GetConnectionString(“BackOffice”));
services.AddHttpClient();`
```

if you know please help me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The keyword you are looking for is 'Configure Polling Interval'. Hangfire polls SQL server for any jobs that needs to be executed and default is 15 seconds. You can change that in `SqlServerStorageOptions` [documented here](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html#configuring-the-polling-interval)

Excerpt from link:

```
var options = new SqlServerStorageOptions
{
    SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero
};

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("<name or connection string>", options);
```

Comment: I try it and also check database every 15 second ,